# How to write a TypeScript type utility that narrows union types in an object?

Tags: typescript

I've got a bunch of generated types (via GraphQL codegen) that look like this:

```
type X = {
  a?: Maybe<number>
  b?: Maybe<Array<MyType> | MyType>
  c?: Maybe<MyType2>
  d?: Maybe<Array<MyType3> | MyType3>
}

// Maybe is:
// type Maybe<T> = T | null | undefined;
```

For fields `b` and `d`, the codegen does the right thing according to GraphQL spec (see [this issue](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/4888)) but in my specific codebase, I need to transform all the types to basically this:

```
type X2 = {
  a?: Maybe<number>
  b?: Maybe<Array<MyType>>
  c?: Maybe<MyType2>
  d?: Maybe<Array<MyType3>>
}
```

How to write a **type utility** that does this?

(Manually, it would be done like this:)

```
type X2 = Omit<X, 'b' | 'd'> & {
  b?: Maybe<Array<MyType>>;
  d?: Maybe<Array<MyType3>>;
};
```

Comment: For this to be a [mcve] it would be nice to see some explicit definitions of your `MyType`s.  I don't want to write something up and find out that `MyType3 extends Array<MyType2>` or something weird like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to tease union members apart from each other, and I'm not 100% sure about the general use case, but here's one way you might approach it:

```
type Xform<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Maybe<infer V> ?
  Extract<V, Array<any>>[number] extends infer R ?
  T[K] extends Maybe<Array<R> | R> ?
  Maybe<Array<R>>
  : T[K] : T[K] : T[K]
}

type X2 = Xform<X>;
/* type X2 = {
    a?: Maybe<number>;
    b?: Maybe<MyType[]>;
    c?: Maybe<MyType2>;
    d?: Maybe<MyType3[]>;
} */
```

Basically what I'm doing is: for each key `K` in the keys of `T`, I'm checking the property value `T[K]`.  If any of my tests fail I will just return the property value unchanged as `T[K]`.  The tests I'm performing: is `T[K]` assignable to `Maybe<V>` for some `V`?  If so, find any members of a union `V` that are `Array<any>` and get their element type, and save it into a new type parameter `R` (for convenience).  Then finally: is `T[K]` assignable to `Maybe<Array<R> | R>`?  If so, then return `Maybe<Array<R>>`.  So we're looking for properties of the form `Maybe<Array<XYZ> | XYZ>` and converting them to `Maybe<Array<XYZ>>`, otherwise we're leaving them alone.

It's always possible that edge cases will pop up; if any of the types `MyType` or `XYZ` are themselves arrays or if you have unions of other things (e.g., `Maybe<MyType[] | MyType2>`), but hopefully this at least gives you some direction.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsnAFzIgCuAtgEbSEC+hoksiKG2eATMkRJ0KAZzBRQAc2atw0eEjRZcEAMwDiyAG6jxUgNwzChAPQm0cdA2TARZQmBUWrEADyYAfMgC8yTMgAfSioAGxDA5CoQABMIGFAIaMMHJwANHw0SOAB+ClRLBldqemgPTTpc50KAQSgoS1duFS8gprwykgRK-JdG5T4O5Gjugrda+vQ+njUWpWnVMpYUvGRUmAB7KBp3L19BZABtAGkbEGQAawh0dZg-AF0KTGO75AgAD0gYkSq3UBhoZAANS82U0AFEPvUEGBXICADTIcYNOAgdAeDwHYoMKAvd6faLfP4AgBKyFBJCeR1xHwgXx+riRk2Js2ZZM0PRqdQazMGj2eyD5VIFfmeRkcK1S-F8a0221SHkMJgAVMhxShJRl9lkRr0saVDCQhDrCm0IAc7grNJ1jW5TbxLYahjapipVObLUxkEqTMY1atePlqHBwntNDk8qMirRsYMKhHeoyXe1Bl14yb+hB7ZphmmxlzJqaFotjLEECE4FAUFoK8g3rwKJLA1Rg4ZS+XK9oa3WG7x9MgzJR1q86ptkDQICjvmAABYoNXfCtz2fIERwcdAA)

Comment: This is fantastic, and seems to work great for the graphql-code-generator use case. Thank you!